# Getting started with Haxe

Tags: haxe

Could you suggest me good articles and tutorials about Haxe besides the official documentation?

I am looking for resources that target not only beginners, but experienced Java / Javascript developers as well.

Comment: Are you developing with pure Haxe in mind or HaxeNME?

Comment: You can test (and save) Haxe programs online at at http://try.haxe.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ralcr.com
look at this guy and his lib, I believe it has good sources for you there.